# VB2010 read data from .txt file to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 4 columns. The first 3 columns is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn while the last column is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

I have my .txt file and inside of it is:

```
Joshua,5/8/14,Paid,Yes
John Kevin,5/8/14,Paid,No
```

Then i have my code:

```
Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\1\Desktop\students.txt")
TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {","}
While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
    Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()
    If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
        Next
    End If
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row1)
End While
```

My code work like this:

> ```
> Joshua,5/8/14,Paid,Yes
>
> "Joshua" will be displayed in first column.
> "5/8/14" will be displayed in second column
> "Paid" will be displayed in third column
> "Yes" and "no" will be displayed in fourth column (combo box) and there are options
> ```

All columns are working in except on the fourth column. There is an error:

> The following exception occured in the DataGridView:
>
> System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
>
> To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

How can i fix it? I want the output that if the text in .txt file is "**Yes**" in the combo box it will auto select Yes, if "No" in .txt file it will select no in the output.

Comment: have you already filled with `yes/no` in `combobox` or what ?

Comment: @creator no, i dont want to filled it through program. I want to get the options from .txt file through splitting by "|" in every lines.

Comment: in your code your `4th column` will filled with `yes|no`